# Java Security Manager: Restrictions on code from external jar loaded via ServiceLoader

Tags: java, serviceloader, java-security-manager

**What am I trying to achieve?** 
I am working on a java application that can be extended by additional jars that get integrated via ServiceLoader. These loaded extensions should run with some restrictions by the SecurityManager, of course simply to improve the security. As an example each Extension shall get one specific directory where it can store whatever, but access to any other file/folder should be restricted. The main application is trusted code and can therefore run without any restrictions. Furthermore the main application provides some api implementations for each extension that shall also run without restrictions. That means an extension mustn't access a file outside of its directory but when the extension is calling an api method that tries to access any other file, the access should be granted.

**Question**
How can I achieve the mentioned behaviour that only 'direct' calls from extension classes get restricted but not any code from the main application?
Running extensions in different threads/threadGroups might be a good solution anyway but since calls to the api might run under the same thread(group) it might not help to identify whether access should be restricted or not based only on the thread.

**Example**
I created a simplified test environment. On one hand there are these two interfaces:

```
public interface Extension {
    void doSomethingRestricted();
    void doSameViaApi(ExtensionApi api);
}

public interface ExtensionApi {
    void doSomethingWithHigherPermissions();
}
```

For testing I created a jar containing this extension:

```
public class SomeExtension implements Extension {

    public void doSomethingRestricted() {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    }

    public void doSameViaApi(final ExtensionApi api) {
        api.doSomethingWithHigherPermissions();
    }
}
```

In the main application I would like do something like this:

```
final ExtensionApi api = () -> System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
try {
    final URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() });
    for(final Extension extension : ServiceLoader.load(Extension.class, urlClassLoader)) {
        extension.doSomethingRestricted();
        extension.doSameViaApi(api);
    }
}
```

So when I call `extension.doSomethingRestricted();` it should result in a SecurityException but calling `extension.doSameViaApi(api);` should work just fine. 
So both methods try to do the same but one does try to do it via the api call. The only approach I could think of is iterating through the call history and checking the classloaders to analyze whether the access request is based on trusted code or extension code. But I feel like this might be a nasty error-prone solution so maybe I missed some better approaches?

Comment: As long as you go the `AccessController` way and don't attempt to mess with threads yourself (read: attempt to reinvent the default `SecurityManager`), it should generally (except for some edge cases such as `RuntimePermission("exitVm.*")` that require a custom class loader to circumvent) be sufficient to grant the needed permissions to each JAR via the .policy file. `ExtensionApiImpl.doSomethingWithHigherPermissions` would then use `AccessController.doPrivileged` to exercise just its own permissions (or a subset thereof), as opposed to the intersection of its own and the extension's.

Comment: Thinking about this anew, rather than having to provide one API method per "privileged" operation, wouldn't it instead be easier to grant some minimal, potentially variable, set of permissions to each `Extension`, such that it can directly execute whatever logic it requires? Sure there are some permissions that are "all-or-nothing" (e.g. `ReflectPermission`) and must thus never be granted to extensions directly, but wouldn't it be viable to grant things like read access to select system properties or file system subtrees?

Comment: Yeah that is probably a fair point. But this was also just a simplified example that I also used for testing. I am not really worried about system properties. Access to the file system on the other hand is indeed one thing I want to secure. So in the end every Extension shall get it's own storage directory and access to any other folder shall be restricted for Extensions.

Answer (score 3):

First ensure your "main" JAR's classes get to enjoy full privileges. Programmatically this may be accomplished as follows:

```
package q46991566;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // policy configuration contents: this JAR gets all permissions, others get nothing
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("grant {};\n\ngrant codebase \"")
                .append(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation())
                .append("\" {\n\tpermission java.security.AllPermission;\n};\n");
        // temp-save the policy configuration
        Path policyPath = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
        Files.write(policyPath, Collections.singleton(sb.toString()));
        // convey to the default file-backed policy provider where to obtain its configuration from;
        // leading equals ensures only the specified config file gets processed
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "=".concat(policyPath.toUri().toURL().toString()));
        // establish a policy; "javaPolicy" is the default provider's standard JCA name
        Policy.setPolicy(Policy.getInstance("javaPolicy", null));
        // policy loaded; backing config no longer needed
        Files.delete(policyPath);
        // establish a security manager for enforcing the policy (the default implementation is more than
        // sufficient)
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        // ...
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you will either have to a) modify the JRE distribution's `java.policy` (or specify a different configuration via the `policy.url.n` properties in `java.security`), or b) replace the implementation of the System `ClassLoader` with one that statically grants `AllPermission` to the `ProtectionDomain` associated with classes loaded from the "main" JAR.

Secondly, when loading `Extension`s from some JAR, employ a `URLClassLoader` subclass that a) manages extension-specific directories and b) includes a `java.io.FilePermission` in the permission collection being statically accorded to the protection domain mapped to its defined classes. Crude sample implementation (note that there is no persistent relationship between an extension JAR and a directory; also note that two `Extension`s originating from the same JAR (but loaded by different class loaders, of course) will get different directories):

```
package q46991566;

import java.io.FilePermission;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.Permission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class ExtensionLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    private static void copyPermissions(PermissionCollection src, PermissionCollection dst) {
        for (Enumeration<Permission> e = src.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            dst.add(e.nextElement());
        }
    }

    private final CodeSource origin;
    private final PermissionCollection perms = new Permissions();
    private final Path baseDir;

    public ExtensionLoader(URL extensionOrigin) {
        super(new URL[] { extensionOrigin });
        origin = new CodeSource(Objects.requireNonNull(extensionOrigin), (Certificate[]) null);
        try {
            baseDir = Files.createTempDirectory(null);
            perms.add(new FilePermission(baseDir.toString().concat("/-"), "read,write,delete"));
            copyPermissions(super.getPermissions(origin), perms);
            perms.setReadOnly();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource cs) {
        return (origin.implies(cs)) ? perms : super.getPermissions(cs);
    }

    // ExtensionApiImpl (or ExtensionImpl directly -- but then ExtensionLoader would have to be relocated
    // into a separate, also fully privileged JAR, accessible to the extension) can call this to relay to
    // extensions where they can persist their data
    public Path getExtensionBaseDir() {
        return baseDir;
    }

    // optionally override close() to delete baseDir early

}
```

Lastly, for unprivileged `Extension`s to be able to execute privileged operations via `ExtensionApi`, the latter's implementation must wrap privileged method (methods issuing `SecurityManager::checkXXX` requests) invocations within `Privileged(Exception)Action`s and pass them to `AccessController::doPrivileged`; e.g.:

```
ExtensionApi api = () -> {
    AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("/root/Documents/highly-sensitive.doc"), Collections.singleton("trusted content"),
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    });
};
```

For details on the (proper) use of "privileged blocks", refer to the `AccessController` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html) and the "Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE" [document](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9).